# Software loading error problem

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, sql-server-2005, vb6

VB6 & SQL Server 2005

```
When i run the Windows based Software exe file, 
it is showing the login page, 
after login page - no screen is displaying, 
I checked the task manager, in task manager it is showing as software as running,
But there is no page is appearing.
```

Is any firewall blocking or some other issue. But software is running with out displaying anythings.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: is this happening when you're trying to program an AI library? or run excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your code. Specifically the code that run after the login screen has unloaded. Maybe you are running a com object that does not have an interface and does not unload, for instance a dll. Or perhaps a function that runs a routine that does not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to log into the server with the same credentials by using a different program such as SQL Server Management Studio?

If you are still unable to log into the server through a different EXE, then I would suspect a firewall blocking the port.  Otherwise, the problem might be in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your connection string has an unlimited connection timeout (value of zero), and you can't connect, but you can't timeout. Set an explicit timeout by adding to your connection string `Connection Timeout=15;`, run the application, and wait the 15 seconds for an error message.